# how to check if bytes32 begins with certain bytes?

Tags: solidity

how do i gas-efficiently check if a bytes32 begins with certain bytes?

the user gives me a bytes32 input, and i want to check if it start with 4 zero bytes.

thank you

Comment: What is your input to this problem?

Comment: `function startsWith(bytes32 x, bytes32 y) pure returns (bool) {return (x & y) == y;}`

Comment: thanks, i get a bytes32 value as an input and need to see if it starts with some certain bytes. if the first 4 bytes are zero

Comment: Yeah that part is clear enough in your question. But there are two inputs here, as you can see in the possible solution that I gave you, which assumes that both inputs are `bytes32`. And you are stating only the type of the first input here!

Comment: okay, well yeah, the user gives me a bytes32 input, and i  want to check if it start with 4 zero bytes. that might be a bytes4 then ?

Comment: No, if this is all you want, then you don't need a second input. But please update your question!

Comment: You only need to check `(uint256(input) & 0x00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff) == 0`.

Comment: Or possibly `(uint256(input) & 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00000000) == 0`.

Comment: thank you. ah so i treat it simply as a number. makes sense, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Testing on remix the cheapest function I got uses 352 gas for execution

```
function g0(bytes32 x, bytes4 y) public pure returns (bool) {
    return bytes4(x) == y;
}
```

Comment: do you think I should delete my answer?

Comment: @TheRenaissance Please don't delete it. I think it is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to gas efficiency, unfortunately.

From the [Solidity docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.7.1/types.html#fixed-size-byte-arrays):

> Index access: If `x` is of type `bytesI`, then `x[k]` for `0 <= k < I` returns the `k` th byte (read-only).

So:

```
function fourLeadingZeroBytes(bytes32 b) public pure returns (bool) {
    return b[0] == 0 && b[1] == 0 && b[2] == 0 && b[3] == 0;
}
```

Comment: From the question: "how do i **gas-efficiently** check...?".

Comment: is this gas inefficient? I couldn't find a good way to check.

Comment: fwiw @goodvibration , I also couldn't get your solutions to work. I'm assuming it's my own lack of experience with bitwise in Solidity, but could it be that the visors you suggest aren't taking any of the rest of the byte string into account? I kept on getting `false` if any of the bytes returned something other than `0`, not just the first 4.

Comment: Regarding the gas - your solution is the most trivial one, so presumably, there is no worse solution in terms of gas. Is there a better one? Maybe not, but obviously no way to compare when there is only one option. Comparison (once you do have another solution) is easy BTW - you declare a state variable `uint public gasUsed;`, and then you call each solution from a function which starts with `uint gasLeft = gasleft();`, and ends with `gasUsed = gasLeft - gasleft();`.

Comment: Finally, you need to run these two test functions from an off-chain script, where each function operates on a "clean" (i.e., brand new) instance of the contract, and then print the value of `gasUsed`.

Comment: Regarding your failed experiment with my suggestion, you can share what you've tried and I can then see what's wrong with it (or with my suggestion, as you claim).

Comment: @goodvibration where should I share? I don't mean to accuse you of being wrong, btw, just was trying to figure out why I couldn't get it to work

Comment: What exactly did you write in your test?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113292/discussion-between-the-renaissance-and-goodvibration).